# JSON language parser; what is meant here

Tags: php, json

Sorry for this dumb question, But in the quote below from [here](http://www.openajax.org/whitepapers/Ajax%20and%20Mashup%20Security.php) the author states it's better to use a JSON Language parser, without giving an example *(hence, a more....)*.
I'm Using PHP functions like json_encode/decode . But do we need additional functions to parse json on the client side? it seems slightly confusing to me since JSON seems like the normal way to represent an object in javascript.

> Listing 12. Checking a JSON string with a regular expression
>
> var my_JSON_object = !(/[^,:{}[]0-9.-+Eaeflnr-u \n\r\t]/.test(
>       text.replace(/"(.|[^"])*"/g, ' '))) &&
>       eval('(' + text + ')');
>
> However, it is important to note that these regexp-style JSON parsers
>   (e.g., http://www.json.org/json.js) have subtle security issues, e.g.,
>   they allow referencing variables from the calling JavaScript program.
>   Imagine that the JSON message should contain a password for
>   authentication purposes and the program has local variable which
>   contains the "benchmark" password. The message might now simply
>   reference that variable, passing authentication without the attacker
>   having to know the password!
>
> Hence, a more secure alternative is using a JSON language parser to
>   parse the JSON data. Since the grammar of JSON is fairly simple, you
>   can implement such a parser easily without large performance penalty.

Comment: You might end up using something like [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the client side.

Comment: Thanks Blanchard I use that function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem here is that javascript code uses eval, which means it will actually execute some code, which could potentially introduce some kind of vulnerability

if you don't use eval (php json_decode does not use eval) or any other decoder which does not use eval - you're good

Comment: Thanks Lashame! just to be clear we don't need to do extra stuff at the client side right? Just don't implement a self made serverside parser

Comment: @rinserepeat yep, don't invent bicycles and use existing solutions (like json_decode on server side or  JSON.parse on client side) and try to avoid eval anywhere in your code